# Python throws error, but still mutates tuple - is this a Python REPL bug?

Tags: python

With the following code, we can see that the modify operation in the last line fails - Python throws an error `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

However, if we look at the line below and print `a`, we see that it *did* indeed do the operation of `+= [1]`.

Why is this? Shouldn't the variable `a` *not* be mutated if the REPL gives an error?

```
[nhouk@computer:~] $ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov  4 2021, 15:29:10) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = ([2, 3], "a", "b")
>>> a[0] += [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
>>> a
([2, 3, 1], 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: Tuples are immutable, so you can't assign to them at an index. But you probably pull out the list, add to it, and try to update the tuple all in one line.

Comment: Python 3.5 has been EOL for a long time. The same thing happens in 3.10 though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **tuple** is not mutated. The **list contained in the tuple** is.

`a[0] += [1]` is (*roughly*) `a[0] = a[0] + [1]` (with the small nuance that it does **not** create a new list, so it is better compared to `a[0].append(1)`). The right side successfully executes and appends `1` to the list, then the error is raised when you try to assign back to the tuple (`a[0] = ...`).

To achieve the same result without getting the error, use `append` directly:

```py
a[0].append(1)
```

Comment: Worth noting, is that really the `+=` is the issue, since it is an in-place operation. `a[0] = a[0] + [1]` does not alter the referenced list, and `a[0]` will still be `[2, 3]`.

Comment: Better solution to "solve" the issue: Use `a[0].extend([1])` or `a[0].append(1)`.

Comment: @deepspace - The error occurs when you try to assign back to the tuple, however, when you print the tuple in the last line, it does indeed appear that the tuple was indeed modified?!? Did the assignment to the tuple fail (as according to the error), or did it succeed?

In other words, you state that the tuple was NOT mutated, but when we print the tuple later, it clearly is modified.

Comment: Again. The tuple is not being modified. What is modified is just the list which is contained inside the tuple. These are not the same.